# How to specify the sampling rate of the iPhone GPS?

Tags: iphone, ios4, gps

Does anyone know how to specify the sampling rate of the iphone GPS?

I read somewhere that it's 1Hz, how do I specify it?

Thx
Antoine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple simply does not expose an API to set the sampling rate. Your best options which should be sufficient is to set your [desired accuracy](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/Reference/reference.html) using `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` or `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` for the highest levels.